# (nested) list in list of custom object

Tags: c#, list, object, static, nested

I have a list (actually an ObservableCollection) of objects (type object defined in a class I made)  and each object has it's own list of objects.
It's a list of archives and each archive has a list of files.

When the "enabled" property of an archive is set, I need to check if there isn't already another archive which is enabled which has the same files. If so, I need to do some things.

So if I have (eg)1000 archvies and I enable an archive, I must search the files list of each archive (= each list of files in a list of 1000 archives) in search for a match.

1. Is that a bad implementation? Would it be better to make an extra list which contains the files of archives which are enabled? Or perhaps another way of doing this which is better?
2. Would it be a good idea to define the list in the archive class and make it static or should I just define it in the class which uses the list (there will always be only ONE list of archives)

thanks (newb trying to learn through practice here)

Answer (score 1):

Along with your `ObservableCollection<Archive>`, I might include a `HashSet<File>`s. (`File` will need to properly implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`) This will let you quickly see if files already exist in any other archive.

```
IList<Archive> archives = new ObservableCollection<Archive>();
ISet<File> files = new HashSet<File>();

void OnArchiveEnabled(Archive archive)
{
    foreach (var file in archive.Files)
    {
        if (!files.Add(file))
        {
            //file already exists, do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I've omitted how `OnArchiveEnabled` is triggered (maybe have the `Archive.Files` property be an `ObservableCollection<File>`), and there's no way in this implementation to disable an archive. To disable an archive, you could recreate the `files` set, or change `files` to a `Dictionary<File, IList<Archive>>` (a dictionary from files to the enabled archives that they're in) and tweak the logic a bit.

Comment: thanks for your answer! so you suggest that i use an extra list but use a hashset instead of "normal" list? because it searches faster?
but if the file already exists I won't know to which archive the already existing file belongs?

Comment: Exactly. If you need to know to which archives the already existing file belongs, then use a `Dictionary<File, IList<Archive>>`. If you only need to know of one other archive, you can make that a `Dictionary<File, Archive>`

Comment: Can I ask you another question: Why do you declare your ObservableCollection with IList()? Just your style or is there more to it? I could also declare it without that or by making my list a seperate class implementing observablecollection and having archive as child class

Comment: Just a style thing. In my example, I only needed it to act as an `IList<T>`, so I used that instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a bad implementation?

Yes, because it is rather slow, `O(N+M)` time complexity for search query.

> Would it be a good idea to define the list in the archive class ...

I have a better suggestion to use an extra index.

#### Step 1

Figure out when two files are same, e.g.:

- name matches
- name and other attributes matches
- digital signature matches
- (some) content matches

#### Step 2

Given a match metric from Step 1 you can build up an index that you search in Step 3

#### Step 2.1

Making a fast index is a hard thing. The fastes index would work in `O(1)` time complexity, which means that if you query it, it will return you result in constant time, independently of the number of archives and files. I would first demand this performance. If this cannot be done, I would store the metrics in a sorted order, so that you can run a `binary search` on it with a damn fast `O(logN)` time complexity.

So let's try making it in O(1). Suppose the metric is match by file name (is not important, purely for simplicity). Dictionary data structure would allow you to:

1. Check if there is any file "known" to be in any archive
2. Retrieve a list of the archive names, where this file found

```
-----------------------------------
Key         |      Value
-----------------------------------
Foo.txt     |  Archive1, Archive43
Bar.txt     |  Archive2
```

Note: you will have to maintain the consistency of the index, so update the index when a change is made to the archive content. This can get tricky!

#### Step 3

Now it's time to query your index! Given you followed Step 1 and 2, this is trivial, just ask a dictionary for the metric, get the result. If there is only one entry, it's your archive, if several then you know which archive stores the same file.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! If I understand it correctly, you are suggesting the same thing as in the comment on Tim S' post, right? Keeping my normal list of archives with nested list of files and use anther separate list which is a dictionary? And do you suggest I declare both in the class which uses them instead of making them static and declaring them in the archive class?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I would move away from `static` as it is not unit-test friendly. It also make sense to use a separate class for the index - separation of concerns. Make each class responsible for only one thing.